# Why Android Studio emulator is upside down when rotating in landscape view?

Tags: android, emulation, landscape

I am a newbie on Android programming, and I am using the latest version of Android Studio on a Mac.

For some reason, the emulator gives me an upside-down display when I rotate the device in the landscape. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Thank you in advance!

All the best,

Fab.

Comment: it might be due to some manifest setting if its limited to some screens or  activity

Comment: Thanks, Akash for your reply, but actually that happens with any application, Chrome browser included.

Comment: do you use macbook with m1 processor?

Comment: No, a regular MacPro Intel based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, but running emulator in a separate window fixes it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! This is clearly a bug that should be addressed in Android Studio, but your suggestion made the trick ;)